# Where can I find the link between field answers and the user who submitted it?

Tags: 7, users

Noob here. I can't figure out how entity forms stores which user submitted each answer for it's fields on the database.

All I can see is a table for each field, and the columns within being: Entity_type, bundle, deleted, entity_id, revision_id, language, delta & Field_(the name of my field).

None of which tells me which user submitted each answer. Yet drupal and entity forms clearly knows which user submitted each answer, because when I go to (Administration > Structure > entityform types > my form > form submissions) I can see a table of every submission with the name of each user who submitted it, and I can see all their answers.

So where the heck is this being stored on the database? If it matters, my database was built with phpmyadmin.

Thanks in advance for your help, I really appreciate it. I'm sorry if my terms are all jumbled and wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for "entityform" table - column "uid" gives you user id of the user who submitted the form.